# Function to output styled-component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-np4kec)

Its a super simple react app with a styled-component.

Is it possible to have a function to output the styled-component that I can pass in values like my attempt that is commented out.

I'd like to sue the `Block` styled-component but change the color each time

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const Block = styled.div`
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
`

const createBlock = (col) => {
  return(
    Block = styled.div`
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background: col;
    `
  )
}

const App = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <Block/>
      {createBlock(red)}
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
const createBlock = (col) => {
  return styled.div`
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background: ${col};
    `
}

const App = () => {
  const StyledBlock = createBlock('red');

  return (
    <StyledBlock>
      <p>Some content</p>
    </StyledBlock>
  );
}
```